# Command line installation of Code Signing certificates, .p12 files, and mobileprovisions

Tags: iphone, macos

I work at a company who does 3rd party iOS development for various enterprises. I've been tasked with researching a better way to build and deploy code to these enterprises. Based on the Apple TOS, they cannot use an application signed with our Enterprise certificate (they're not "in house"). The code needs to be signed with their (our clients) Enterprise certificate. Here are a few possible solutions I've seen -

1) Send the code to the client, and have the client build it. **This is a no-go**.

2) Create a library with the application code and send the .so file, and the headers, to the client for building. **We're currently doing it this way but are looking at making this easier on the client/us.**

3) Have the client send us their certificate, mobileprovision, and .p12 file and then we build the application using their certificate. **This could work but could become a management nightmare.**

We've come up with an idea that is kind of a mix of these ideas. The idea involves building a customer portal where the client can upload their files (cert, p12, provision) to our Mac server and the Mac will automagically build their application, properly signed. The problem I'm having, however, is I can't seem to find out how to automate the installation of certificates and provisions.

So with that said, does anyone know of a way to install a CodeSign certificate (with a .p12 file) and a mobile provision file from the command line? Once installed is there also a way to remove the items from the command line?

Any help, ideas, and/or input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to manage those resources in the keychain using the `security` (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html) command. The script I'm using to control command line builds might be a useful reference: https://gist.github.com/949831

Comment: This looks like it might be what we need, but I haven't had time to test it yet. I'll be looking into this today, so hopefully this will provide us our answer! :) Many many thanks! (Will mark as answer if this indeed does work)

Comment: Great. If you find anything that you want to add to that script which you think would be useful for developers in general please let me know on the gist or at http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/05/04/automated-ad-hoc-builds-using-xcode-4/

Comment: I've been able to get this (mostly) working thanks to your input. There are still some pieces I have to put together but this got me over my hump. Many many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly I've only ever had a maximum 2 external clients plus my own stuff at one time, so it was mostly only the same nightmare that it usually is by default, but how bad would it be if you had to manually do everything EXCEPT the provisioning profiles? In my experience once the client certs got added I never really messed with them again even with new projects (from the same clients.)

You could handle the provisioning profiles by simply copying the files into ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles, and deleting them when no longer needed. It sounds like you are already set up to automate that process.

If you're currently installing the provisioning profiles by "dropping them onto xcode" I'd suggest you do it by copying into the folder anyway, because then the file names are preserved and so you actually can tell what you have installed by simply looking at the folder.

Comment: The problem for us is, some of our clients are uncomfortable giving their certificates to sit, indefinitely, on a developer machine. Our solution was to try and create an automated build process where the client can upload their files to a secured server, get a build, and then have their information removed. It makes the process more secure and eases the minds of our clients (so we hope!).

Comment: In that case it would seem like Jonah's answer would take care of the certs for you. I'm pretty sure that's the hard part, and the provisioning profiles are just a matter of copy/delete. is 1) not an option because you don't want the clients to have access to source? If not have you considered using a client-side build script that first does something like an SVN update of all of the files needed to do the build? I've never done it that way for iOS, but have for Windows-hosted projects.

Comment: First, your comment on the provisioning profiles was super helpful. I've changed the way we do it now to your suggestion:D We've considered a client side script to pull from SVN and build but, for various reasons (some I don't understand), our CEO is 100% against giving out any of source code or any kind of access to the source code, regardless if it's removed after or not. We also have a few clients who are 100% against giving us their cert. They are afraid of it sitting on a dev machine indefinitely. It's really an annoying problem, but you and Jonah have pointed us closer to a solution!

Comment: Have a look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html and see if the "build and archive" feature might allow you to send a pre-built app to a client for them to sign themselves. I've never tried it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That will make this process a lot easier (no need to command line build if I could just copy the app file to the server!).